# Java email - Exception Server is not trusted

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, glassfish-3, apache-commons

I'm using apache commons mail to send emails. Unfortunately I'm getting following Exception:

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : mail.xxx.com:25
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1242)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1267)
    at com.xxx.UserBean.sendMail(UserBean.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
.
.
.
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: Server is not trusted: mail.xxx.com
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1880)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:648)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1232)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server is not trusted: mail.xxx.com
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:443)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1875)
    ... 92 more
```

And here is my java code:

```
    public void sendMail(){
    try {  
        SimpleEmail mail = new SimpleEmail();
        mail.setTLS(true); 
        mail.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("user","xyxyxyxy"));
        mail.setHostName("mail.xxx.com");            
        mail.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.auth", true);
        mail.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.debug", true);
        mail.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.port", "587");
        mail.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        mail.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtpserver");

        mail.addTo("user@server.com", "user");
        mail.setFrom("info@xxx.com");
        mail.setSubject("Bla Bla");
        mail.setMsg("Bla Bla again");
        mail.send();
                } catch (Exception ex) {   
        logger.info("Senden der Email ist gescheitert!", ex);            
    }
 }
```

I've already read many threads and tried many hints. I'm stuck here!
I should mention that I'm able to send emails with another method using "javax.mail". But I'd like to move to apache.

I'm thankful for any help.

Comment: I'd like to reformulate my question, how can I setup "apache.commons.mail" to use my Glassfish mail session? Is it possible to make a reference like mail.session.jndi.name=mail/MailSession, but where? Javax.mail works fine with glassfish, I don't even need to authenticate.

Answer (score 4):

setTLS (Transport layer security) to false. If you are not using. When it is true its expected to be mail.xxx.com trusted server.

`mail.setTLS(false);`

Comment: `Caused by: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
        com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 554 5.7.1 <user@server.com>: Relay access denied`

Comment: The message you're sending to the xxx.com server is not addressed to users in the xx.com domain so that xxx.com server would need to forward the message to another server, and it's refusing to do that.  Possibly it's doing that because you haven't authenticated to the server.  Check the debug output to see if authentication is happening.  If it isn't, try changing your property settings to use a string "true" instead of the boolean constant.

Comment: I tried everything; disabled/enabled authentication with literal/boolean true property. I enabled debug mode, but I don't get more information. The thrown error is still the same as above!

Comment: With "javax.mail" I don't need to authenticate at all, I setup a Javamail session on Glassfish v3.1.2.

Answer (score 3):

Finally Solved. I tried everything to get authenticated at my exchange server.
use the code below:

```
Properties props = (Properties)System.getProperties().clone();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);

//Bypass the SSL authentication
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", false);
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", false);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `Spring-Boot-Mail`, try adding this line to you `.properties` file:

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=smtp.mandrillapp.com
```